# Does dart automatically determine which map type to use?

Tags: dart

I was working on some code very similar to the example below that always seems to resolve in order, despite never specifying that I want the map object to be ordered.

```
Map<String, Map<String, int>> map = {
  "a" : {"value": 1, "price": 2},
  "c" : {"value": 3, "price": 8},
  "x" : {"value": 2, "price": 1},
  "b" : {"value": 1, "price": 8},
};
map.forEach((name, map) => print(map));
```

This always results in

```
a
c
x
b
```

**Note**: This is what I want it to do, I am just looking for an explanation as to why it does things this way, as it would be interesting to get a better understanding of why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart's core libraries have a couple implementations of `Map`. Lets look!

*NOTE: I am referencing the `dev` channel SDK, the one to be affiliated with Dart 2 (and being used for Flutter), so if you're currently using the `stable` SDK, the docs might look a little different*

If you navigate to our docs:

- -> https://api.dartlang.org/dev
- -> `dart:core` (https://api.dartlang.org/dev/dart-core/dart-core-library.html)
- -> `Map` (https://api.dartlang.org/dev/dart-core/Map-class.html)

You'll see the following description:

> Maps, and their keys and values, can be iterated. The order of iteration is defined by the individual type of map.

And for the default constructor (the one used for `{}` syntax, as well):

> Creates a `LinkedHashMap` instance that contains all key/value pairs of `other`.

You could create a `Map` of one of the other two types, `HashMap` (unordered; https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.35.0/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html) or `SplayTreeMap` (sorted; https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.35.0/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) if you want different behavior.

The `HashMap` class (explicitly) can be useful where you want a bit less memory usage, or where order is explicitly not useful or not desired. For most uses cases, as you've mentioned, `LinkedHashMap` is totally appropriate.

Cheers!